# Problema no relacionamento Many to Many no Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework, fluent-api

Eu tenho a seguinte situação:

Para realizar uma autenticação, estou utilizando o método antigo para uma pequena aplicação, para atribuição de níveis (roles), como muitos exemplos que se têm pela web afora. Uso o EF e o Postgres para acesso/gravar dados e a Fluent API para fazer o relacionamento *many-to-many* Segue os modelos e o contexto:

**Usuario**

```
    [Table("usuarios", Schema = "public")]
    public class Usuario
    {
        [Key]
        public int usuarioid { get; set; }
        public string descricao { get; set; }
        public string nome { get; set; }
        public string senha { get; set; }

        public IList<Nivel> Niveis { get; set; }

        public Usuario()
        {
            Niveis = new List<Nivel>();
        }
    }
```

**Nivel**

```
[Table("niveis", Schema = "public")]
public class Nivel
{
    [Key]
    public int nivelid { get; set; }
    public string nome { get; set; }    
}
```

**Datacontext**

```
    public class EntidadeDB: DbContext
    {
        public EntidadeDB() : base(nameOrConnectionString: "Conexao") { }

        public DbSet<Usuario> Usuario { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Nivel> Nivel { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Usuario>()
                .HasMany<Nivel>(u => u.Niveis)
                .WithMany()
                .Map(cs =>
                    {                           
                        cs.MapLeftKey("nivelid");
                        cs.MapRightKey("usuarioid");
                        cs.ToTable("nivel_usuarios");
                    });
        }
    }
```

O problema está que quando eu tento gravar ou recuperar os níveis de um determinado usuário, o *count* (lista) vem zerado. Detalhe que inseri manualmente no banco alguns dados na tabela `nivel_usuarios`.

Após algumas pesquisas, encontrei algo que deu certo, porem o autor do artigo usava o *nHibernate* invés do *EF*, segue:

**Usuario**

```
public class User
{

    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Username { get; set; }
    public virtual string Email { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Role> Roles { get; set; }

    public User()
    {
        Roles = new List<Role>();
    }

}

public class UserMap : ClassMapping<User>
{
    public UserMap()
    {
        Table("users");

        Id(x => x.Id, x => x.Generator(Generators.Identity));

        Property(x => x.Username, x => x.NotNullable(true));
        Property(x => x.Email, x => x.NotNullable(true));

        Bag(x => x.Roles, x =>
        {
            x.Table("role_users");
            x.Key(k => k.Column("user_id"));
        }, x => x.ManyToMany(k => k.Column("role_id")));
    }
}
```

Pelo que entendi através da propriedade `Bag`, ele fez o relacionamento/mapeamento das tabelas. Alguém poderia me ajudar a identificar onde estou errando para fazer isso funcionar com o *EF*?

Quando dou um `post` no form, nível vem `null` (ele é um *checkbox*):

[image: Debug]

**Edit:**

Minha *view* está assim:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Niveis.Count; i++)
            {
                <li class="list-group-item">
                    @Html.Hidden("Niveis[" + i + "].Id", Model.Niveis[i].id)
                    <label for="Niveis_@(i)__IsChecked">
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Niveis[i].IsChecked)
                        @Model.Niveis[i].nome
                    </label>
                </li>
            }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Essa abordagem de criar a tabela associativa usando o `ModelBuilder` é meio problemática. No seu lugar, faria uma tabela associativa e não usaria *Fluent API*:

```
public class UsuarioNivel
{
    [Key]
    public int usuarionivelid { get; set; }
    [Index("IUQ_UsuarioNivel_UsuarioId_NivelId", IsUnique = true, Order = 1)]
    public int usuarioid { get; set; }
    [Index("IUQ_UsuarioNivel_UsuarioId_NivelId", IsUnique = true, Order = 2)]
    public int nivelid { get; set; }

    public virtual Usuario Usuario { get; set; }
    public virtual Nivel Nivel { get; set; }
}
```

Eu faria também algumas modificações:

```
[Table("usuarios", Schema = "public")]
public class Usuario
{
    [Key]
    public int usuarioid { get; set; }
    public string descricao { get; set; }
    public string nome { get; set; }
    public string senha { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UsuarioNivel> UsuarioNiveis { get; set; }
}

[Table("niveis", Schema = "public")]
public class Nivel
{
    [Key]
    public int nivelid { get; set; }
    public string nome { get; set; }    

    public virtual ICollection<UsuarioNivel> UsuarioNiveis { get; set; }
}
```

Isto garante que você possa manipular a tabela de associação e controlar melhor as inserções, que não precisam ser manuais.

[`[Index]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.indexattribute(v=vs.113).aspx), introduzido nesta forma a partir do Entity Framework 6.1.0, garante a unicidade do registro associativo. Validações adicionais podem ser necessárias na aplicação para evitar erros estranhos de duplicidade de chave para o usuário.

Comment: Hmm, me soa promissora tua resposta Cigano... não sei seria muito incomodo, mas porque criar tabela associativa com FluentAPI é problemática? E outra, porq ja nao estanciar as Listas do UsuarioNivel nas classes Nivel e Usuario?

Comment: Resolvi aqui Cigano, agora funcionou "like a charm". Sobre não estar vindo os checkbox para o controller é que no Hidden onde passo o id, estava passando com o Id com a letra inicial maiúscula, e no controller estava miniscula.

Comment: Vamos lá. No começo dos meus dias programando em ASP.NET MVC + EF (na época era o 5, se não me engano), eu usava esta notação. Aí vieram dois problemas: 1) Como eu controlo a associação (adicionar e excluir) de forma eficiente? 2) Se eu apenas quiser dados sobre as associações em si, como eu mapeio isso num `DbSet<>`? 3) Se eu quiser colocar campos adicionais na associação, como posso fazer? Em resumo, a *Fluent API* não atende bem nenhum desses 3 pontos.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez se puder acessar: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/115336/entity-framework-many-to-many-ientitychangetracker-erro-como-resolver

Apliquei este exemplo para solucionar la, porém esta sendo criada a tabela gerada pelo many to many normal normalmente, ou seja, se eu adicionar o dbset<> que vc sugere aqui, eu acabo ficando com duas tabelas "iguais". Qual seria as solução?