# Erro ao salvar uma relação Many-To-Many

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Seguindo os modelos que [dessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/100565/problema-no-relacionamento-many-to-many-no-entity-framework), estou tendo problemas ao tentar salvar os dados (chaves de cada um dos registros) na tabela criada para fazer o relacionamento dos dados. Segue o método post que construí:

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Novo(UsuariosNovo form, NivelCheckbox checkbox)
    {
        var usr = new Usuario();

        foreach (var nivelId in form.Niveis)
        {
            var item = new NivelUsuario() { nivelid = checkbox.nivelid, usuarioid = form.usuarioid };
            db.NivelUsuario.Add(item);
        }


        if (db.Usuario.Any(u => u.nome == form.nome))
            ModelState.AddModelError("nome", "O nome do usuario precisa ser unico.");

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return View(form);

        usr.descricao = form.descricao;
        usr.nome = form.nome;
        usr.SetPassword(form.senha);

        db.Usuario.Add(usr);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class NivelCheckbox
{
    public int nivelid { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
    public string nome { get; set; }
}



public class UsuariosNovo
{
    public List<NivelCheckbox> Niveis { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput]
    public int usuarioid { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Obrigatório informar a Descrição")]
    [Display(Name = "Descrição")]
    public string descricao { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Obrigatório informar o Login")]
    [Display(Name = "Login")]
    public string nome { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Obrigatório informar a Senha")]
    [Display(Name = "Senha"), DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string senha { get; set; }
}
```

**View**

```
<div class="panel panel-default col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
    <div class="panel-heading">Niveis</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <ul class="list-group">

            @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Niveis.Count; i++)
            {
                <li class="list-group-item">
                    @Html.Hidden("Niveis[" + i + "].nivelid", Model.Niveis[i].nivelid)
                    <label for="Niveis_@(i)__IsChecked">
                        @Html.CheckBox("Niveis[" + i + "].IsChecked", Model.Niveis[i].IsChecked)
                        @Model.Niveis[i].nome
                    </label>
                </li>
            }
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Quando essa ação é chamada uma exceção é invocada:

> 23503: inserção ou atualização em tabela "nivel_usuarios" viola
>   restrição de chave estrangeira "nivel_usuarios_nivelid_fkey"

Pelo debug que fiz, as id's vem zeradas para o controller, alguem sabe onde estou errando? Ou tem alguma maneira mais correta de se fazer isso? (*Passar o id de nivel e usuario para outra tabela*)

Comment: Poderia colocar na sua pergunta como está o Form também?

Comment: Coloquei a parte dos niveis... Sei que falta as condições para somente adicionar no banco se o Ischecked é true e tals...

Comment: Não entendi essa variável `NivelCheckbox`. As `checkbox` que você precisa já não estão em `UsuarioNovo`?

Comment: Você fala no Controller né? Realmente, estava passando a mais, não era necessário fazer isso, passei esse porque nao estava conseguindo pegar o nivelid no laço foreach... @CiganoMorrisonMendez

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que falta coisas aqui:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Niveis.Count; i++)
{
    <li class="list-group-item">
        @Html.Hidden("Niveis[" + i + "].nivelid", Model.Niveis[i].nivelid)
        <label for="Niveis_@(i)__IsChecked">
            @Html.CheckBox("Niveis[" + i + "].IsChecked", Model.Niveis[i].IsChecked)
            @Model.Niveis[i].nome
        </label>
    </li>
}
```

Falta o índice da linha, como abaixo:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Niveis.Count; i++)
{
    <li class="list-group-item">
        <input type="hidden" name="Niveis.index" id="Niveis_index" value="@(i)" />
        @Html.Hidden("Niveis[" + i + "].nivelid", Model.Niveis[i].nivelid)
        <label for="Niveis_@(i)__IsChecked">
            @Html.CheckBox("Niveis[" + i + "].IsChecked", Model.Niveis[i].IsChecked)
            @Model.Niveis[i].nome
        </label>
    </li>
}
```

Isto faz o *ModelBinder* se organizar melhor e definir garantidamente as variáveis.

Comment: Cigano, consegui resolver o problema de outra maneira,só que agora tem outro problema, quando editar, sincronizar os checkbox, se existir no banco, ele traz checkado, senão traz vazio...

Comment: Acho que você está dificultando muito a solução. O correto seria usar entidades mapeadas em banco e usar `@Html.CheckBoxFor`, mas teria que reformular, e muito, sua solução até então.

Comment: Hmm, mas voce teria algum exemplo disso? E como ficaria no controller pra mim saber se está checado ou nao?

Comment: Poss colocar, mas você vai ter que reformular sua pergunta, pedindo um exemplo em que se troque `@Html.CheckBox` por `@Html.CheckBoxFor`.

Answer (score 0):

Eu consegui resolver o problema da seguinte maneira, somente alterei a action:

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Novo(UsuariosNovo form)
    {
        var usr = new Usuario();

        if (db.Usuario.Any(u => u.nome == form.nome))
            ModelState.AddModelError("nome", "O nome do usuario precisa ser unico.");

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return View(form);

        foreach (var nivelId in form.Niveis)
        {
            var item = new NivelUsuario() { nivelid = nivelId.nivelid, usuarioid = form.usuarioid };

            if (nivelId.IsChecked)
                db.NivelUsuario.Add(item);
        }

        usr.descricao = form.descricao;
        usr.nome = form.nome;
        usr.SetPassword(form.senha);

        db.Usuario.Add(usr);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```