# Entity framework many-to-many IEntityChangeTracker erro. Como resolver?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, code-first

Eu tenho um relacionamento many-to-many e minhas tabelas estão corretas sobre a relação no banco de dados. O problema é que minha inserção funciona perfeitamente quando você não usar uma entidade existente no banco de dados, mas quando eu buscar no banco de dados e adicionar novamente ele entende que não estou apenas "referenciando", mas acrescentando uma nova entidade.

entidade noticia:

```
[Table("Noticia")]
public class
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Titulo { get; set; }

    #region Relationships
    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
    #endregion Relationships
}
```

Tag model:

```
[Table("Tag")]
public class Tag
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    [MinLength(3), MaxLength(30)]
    public string Descricao { get; set; }

    #region Relationships
    [Required]
    public virtual ICollection<Noticia> Noticias { get; set; }        
    #endregion Relationships
}
```

este relacionamendo (ICollection

Controller:

```
[HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(NoticiaViewModel vModel)
    {
         if (vModel != null && vModel.ArquivoImagem != null && vModel.ArquivoImagem.ContentLength > 0)
         {
              vModel.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
              vModel.DataPostagem = DateTime.Now;
              vModel.Tags = ObterTags(vModel.TagsEmLinha, vModel.Id);
              vModel.UsuarioId = User.ToAvatarPrincipal().AvatarIdentity.Id;
              vModel.Imagem = new Imagem
              {
                  Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                  CaminhoImagem = FileUploaderHelper.Upload(vModel.ArquivoImagem, User.ToAvatarPrincipal().AvatarIdentity.TipoUsuario,vModel.Id.ToString())
              };

              if (ModelState.IsValid)
              {
                  ///TODO: Quando a tag já foi utilizada, esta dando erro de primary key já existente na Tag.
                  if (_noticiaService.Gravar(ModelBuilderHelper.BuildNoticia(vModel)))
                  return RedirectToAction("List");
              }
        }
                return View(vModel);
   }

   private List<Tag> ObterTags(string tagsEmLinha)
   {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tagsEmLinha))
        {
             Tag tagFromDb = null;
             var tags = new List<Tag>();
             if (tagsEmLinha.Contains(","))
             {
                  foreach (var tagDescricao in tagsEmLinha.Split(','))
                  {
                       tagFromDb = DefineTag(tags, tagDescricao);
                  }
             }
             else
             {
                  tagFromDb = DefineTag(tags, tagsEmLinha);
             }
             return tags;
        }
        return null;
   }

   private Tag DefineTag(List<Tag> tags, string tagDescricao)
   {
        Tag tagFromDb = _tagService.ObterPor(tagDescricao);
        if (tagFromDb != null)
            tags.Add(tagFromDb);
        else
        {
            tags.Add(new Tag
            {
                 Descricao = tagDescricao
            });
        }

        return tagFromDb;
   }
```

Lembrando que, adicionando uma notícia inexistente com uma tag inexistente, ele insere nas tabelas todas corretamente (insere em noticia, tag e tagNoticia). Mas se eu inserir uma notícia para uma tag que já existe (fazer a relação many-to-many), o erro ocorre:

Erro:

> An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of
>   IEntityChangeTracker.

Answer (score 1):

Alterei meu Service para o seguinte:

```
public bool GravarNoticia(Noticia noticia, List<string> tags)
{
    Noticia novaNoticia = null;

    using (_noticiaRepository)
    {
        try
        {
            novaNoticia = new Noticia
            {
                DataPostagem = noticia.DataPostagem,
                Descricao = noticia.Descricao,
                Id = noticia.Id,
                Imagem = noticia.Imagem,
                Titulo = noticia.Titulo,
                UsuarioId = noticia.UsuarioId,
                Tags = new List<Tag>()
            };

            foreach (var tag in tags)
            {
                var tagFromDb = _noticiaRepository.ObterTag(tag);

                if (tagFromDb != null)
                    novaNoticia.Tags.Add(tagFromDb);
                else
                    novaNoticia.Tags.Add(new Tag
                    {
                        Descricao = tag,
                        Id = Guid.NewGuid()
                    });
            }

            return Gravar(novaNoticia);
        }
        catch (System.Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

O que acontecia era que eu usava duas instâncias diferentes do meu contexto, uma na busca e outra na inserção, aí era onde o conflito acontecia, pois o *Entity Framework* não entendia que era a mesma entidade e tentava inserir novamente por cima de uma já inexistente.

link oficial de onde me baseei para pegar a resposta:
https://lostechies.com/derekgreer/2015/11/01/survey-of-entity-framework-unit-of-work-patterns/